# Why does AcquireRequestState hide Inherited HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState while Application_Start does not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I'm trying to implement `AcquireRequestState` event in my application's Global.asax, but when i add the following code Visual Studio 2010 warns me with the message

> 'TestMe.Global.AcquireRequestState(object, System.EventArgs)' hides
>   inherited member 'System.Web.HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState'. Use
>   the new keyword if hiding was intended.

```
 protected void AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Some code here
 }
```

My question is why is this hiding the base class implementation when the remaining methods of the Application class like `Application_Start`, `Session_Start` are fine ?

Is `AcquireRequestState` declared in the base class, while the remaining methods are just event handlers that are only declared in the Global.asax class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the autowired event name should be `Application_AcquireRequestState`:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Some code here
}
```

Comment: i fel dumb :) , i will accept once SO allows me to